# Apache SVN server requirements?

Tags: linux, apache, svn

Are there any minimum server requirements for using Apache SVN? If not, what are some general server specifications used for Apache SVN? Any information on server capacities for Apache SVN would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you consider using [git](http://git-scm.com/) instead of `svn` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how is this related to the question?

Comment: `git` is a version control system (IMHO better than `svn`), and does not need any HTTP server. So it might be considered! But this is a comment, not an answer!

Answer (score 4):

As long as your team is not extremely large, a very decent server is enough. Even a virtual server with about 1 virtual CPU and 1GB RAM running on a decent real CPU is enough. I'd say it doesn't need to be any faster than a server you'd use as a file server.

I'm using it myself on a very limited v-server and it works very well.

Answer (score 3):

I have yet to find an Apache httpd configured Subversion server that's underpowered. Subversion itself doesn't take up a lot of bandwidth. I would still suggest that the server be dedicated. It isn't that Subversion sucks up a lot of power. More likely, whatever else you do will suck up too much power, and it will slow down Subversion. I was at one site that kept on piling more stuff onto the Subversion server (including database services) and then ware upset that Subversion was slow. Everything on that machine was slow.

The main concern would be bandwidth which seems to matter much more than the server itself. Also, be careful with NFS mounted disks (although Netapps seem fine).

Comment: thanks. By bandwidth, do you mean the number of users?

Comment: No, the network. We have a virtual machine running Subversion with 4Gb of memory and two or four cores. That serves over 100 user, and no one has complained about speed. I use to work with ClearCase and that was the exact opposite. You never had enough resources with ClearCase.

Answer (score 1):

I found this http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#server-requirements but it's probably not enough detail.

Comment: +1 for finding a reference on apache.org :)